# Create one class from the same element in multiple xsd files

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have multiple `xsd` files and all of them make use of a `complexType` called `errorType`. This `errorType` is always the same in all these schemas but since the classes generated from each schema lie in a different package I have a class called `ErrorType` multiple times with exactly the same structure.

Is it possible to let JAXB generate only one class for `errorType`?

PS: It is not possible to change the `xsd` files.

Comment: External binding file? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html

Comment: @fabian would it be possible to define a class which I already have with the appropriate fields and use this instead ?

Comment: @SteveSt Yes, just use `jaxb:class/@ref`.

Comment: The author of the XML Schema definitions wanted to make them different XML Schema types, apparently in different XML namespaces. If they are homogeneous, you may cheat using an XML binding file (see fabian's reference). But make sure to ask the "other side" whether they have taken that decision knowingly or just by happenstance. (I'd be willing to take high odds against one of these sides. `;-)` )